# Running total won't print properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        calc()
        display()
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    totalpr=0
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    global totalpr
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()


main()

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```

The last line of code is indicative of the problem. The display for "totalpr" is not a running tally of, say, 3 entered stocks. It's merely the profit_loss restated. How do I get it to accurately display the running total for however many times someone decides to enter stock data? The way it works: someone enters the sentinel '-999' then the program adds up all the profit_loss from every instance and prints it out. That's it.

Comment: A start would be not setting `totalpr=0` at the top of `calc()`...

Comment: Does not work.`totalpr=0` can be at the top of `calc()` or immediately after `global totarpr`

Comment: You are resetting `totalpr` every time `calc` is called...

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Narrowing down the error makes it easier for you to find the issue by yourself, and makes it easier for us to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `totalpr` every time `calc` is called.

```
def calc():
    totalpr=0  # resets to zero every time
    # ...
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss  # same as `totalpr = 0 + profit_loss`
```

Instead, you have to initialize `totalpr` outside of `calc`:

```
totalpr = 0  # set to zero only once
def calc():
    # ...
    totalpr = totalpr + profit_loss  # same as `totalpr += profit_loss`
```